# Magmi import display 93sku but only load 1

Tags: import, magmi

I am facing a weird behavior using magmi. as you can see in the image, Magmi sql data-source processes 93 sku as it says in Global Stats but only 1/1 sku is imported into magento as it says in run-time infos.

Additionally, that imported record was loaded perfect into the catalog and displayed at frontend but no other record was loaded.

Any idea why this behavior could be happening? brgds!

[image]

my current database table have the following fields:

FieldName => FieldType => Value

- sku = number
- short_description = text
- description = text
- category_ids = text = 45
- type = varchar = simple
- attribute_set = varchar = default
- thumbnail = text
- small_image = text
- image = text
- thumbnail_label = text
- small_image_label = text
- image_label = text
- price = varchar = 11
- cost = varchar = 10
- status = varchar = Active
- name = varchar
- meta_title = text
- meta_description = text
- country_of_manufacture = varchar = US
- weight = varchar = 1
- qty = varchar  = 1
- visibility = varchar = Catalog and Search
- tax_class_id = varchar = 1
- is_in_stock = varchar = 1
- store = varchar = admin
- use_config_manage_stock = integer = 1
- manage_stock = integer = 1

UPDATE: im sharing the .sql table with all the information at google drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_L9grdMhRStSEszVnlyWWFsNTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please check the warning overthrow . If magmi not fount sku it not updated and plz make sure your setting with connection and folder structure is correct

Comment: @AmitKamboj thats the weird thing. as you can see on the image the system detected 93 sku but only load 1 or 1-last in another try. all other 92 or 91 are not take it into consideration.

Comment: @s_h, Did you check the file permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sql has an error in its constructions, many sky were repeated.sorry

Answer (score 0):

Check the mode is correctly set to **create new items & update existing ones**. It could be that you have one product existing already and it is updating the existing product while not creating any new ones. The settings appear after you have loaded your profile in the following section:

```
Directly run magmi with existing profile
Run Magmi With Profile: using mode:
```

Comment: thanks, i tried with the 3 options but nothing happened.